# regex matching for names and surnames: how to accept dots and hyphens?

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to write a simple regex to validate names and surnames. I am having some trouble with special characters.

I want a name to be composed of at least one a-zA-Z , then any combination of space, dot , and the character '

trying to validate as good names such as Penny O'Malley, or Rob M. Johnson

so far I am running this:

```
/^[A-z][A-z\s.']+$/
```

but it does not match the names above; it works for names without . and ' , and doesn't care if there are beginning spaces ....

SOLVED: As per @basher 's request, here is the code I am running in the laravel validator. Funny thing is that I am positive I tried the backslash version first (the one you see below, not the one I put on my original post) and didn't seem to work ...

```
'name' => 'required|between:3,15|regex:/^[A-z][A-z\s\.\']+$/',
'surname' => 'required|between:3,15|regex:/^[A-z][A-z\s\.\']+$/',
```

thanks to everybody that contributed. I am not sure about how to attribute the credit for correct answer among you guys though..
@user2141046 , yes, \s seems to work, at least in laravel framework.

Comment: The regex looks fine.  You may not be implementing it correctly.  Mind posting that code?

Comment: @basher, I added it above. actually it needed escaping of . and ' , funny thing is I am sure that was the first try I did and didn't seem to work. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure you can insert \s into the parenthesis.

try `[a-zA-Z.' ]` or `[a-zA-Z\.\'\ ]` as your second regex (might change according the language)

```
 echo "Rob M. Mc'Fly" > try
 grep --colour "[a-zA-Z\'\.\ ]" !$
 >> Rob M. Mc'Fly  (colors the entire name).
```

also confirmed on perl regex with `^[A-z][A-z\'\.\ ]+`

btw, never remember the ASCII codes so i prefer writing the `A-Za-z` ;)
another thing might be bothering you is hidden chars (leading spaces) or maybe the carriage return (in case there is OS differences), might be good to get rid of the trailing `$` and try again to check it or get rid of the leading `^` and check for the whitespace problem.

Comment: I don't know about Laravel, but generally you can insert character classes (`\s`) into `[]`.

Comment: i also don't know too much about larval, but it might be his problem. each language and it's problems...

Comment: @Dukeling , user2141046 thanks, yes it seems I can insert \s . I kept the /^ $/ because it seemed to cause less fuss and I can survive with a beginning or trailing . ' . Thanks all.